# Ultra win grid column filter

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

i am using ultrawingrid and below is sample dataset

### First Name | Last Name | Age | Place

Vikas | Kunte | 27 | Mysore

Ganesh | Kunte | 25 | Mysore

David | Wiesse | 26 | Bangalore

If i use column filter on Last name column, i see the options as Kunte and Wiesse.

If i select Kunte, my result set shows as below which is fine

Vikas | Kunte | 27 | Mysore

Ganesh | Kunte | 25 | Mysore

Again if i want to filter on Age, is see the options as 27, 25 and 26. Instead i should see the options 27 and 25

Is it possible to do this in infragistics grid ?

Answer (score 0):

The grid has AfterRowFilterDropDownPopulate event in which you can use to remove the items. For this you can use code like this:

var hiddenRows = ultraGrid1.Rows.Where(r => r.IsFilteredOut);

```
            foreach (var hiddenRow in hiddenRows)
            {
                var item = e.ValueList.ValueListItems.Cast<ValueListItem>().
                    FirstOrDefault(i => i.DisplayText == hiddenRow.Cells[e.Column].Text);
                if (item != null)
                {
                    e.ValueList.ValueListItems.Remove(item);
                }
            }
```